# BigQuery UDF with loop

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like an example of a function in BigQuery (SQL), in order to see the syntax needed to create such a function: create a function in BigQuery, using SQL (not JavaScript), where internally an array and loop is created to iterate this array, adding the values ​​of the array and returning the resulting sum (int64).

Comment: Are you set on using a function? This can be done using native StandardSQL.  Also, loops are typically not advised within database environments, as they are typically quite slow when they have to operate on every row of a table/query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

> example of a function in BigQuery (SQL) that "loops" through array's elements and produces sum of its elements

```
create temp function sum_array(a array<INT64>) as ((
  select sum(element) from unnest(a) element
));
```

Below is example of using such function with simplified dummy data

```
#standardSQL
create temp function sum_array(a array<INT64>) as ((
  select sum(element) from unnest(a) element
));
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 1 id, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6 ] arr union all
  select 2, [1, 3, 5, 7, 9] union all
  select 3, [2, 4] 
)
select id, sum_array(arr) sum_elements_of_array 
from `project.dataset.table`
order by id
```

with output

[image]

Comment: @ClaytonBonelli - did you have chance to try?